# JHipster : AngularJS prints null entity while retrieving objects after 1

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

```
angular
    .module('smartLpcApp')
    .controller('CaptionsDetailController', CaptionsDetailController);

CaptionsDetailController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'entity', 'Captions', 'Projects'];

function CaptionsDetailController($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, entity, Captions, Projects) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.captions = entity;
    console.log("Printing entity : "+JSON.stringify(entity));
    vm.load = function (id) {
        Captions.get({id: id}, function(result) {
            vm.captions = result;
        });
    };
    var unsubscribe = $rootScope.$on('smartLpcApp:captionsUpdate', function(event, result) {
        vm.captions = result;
    });
    $scope.$on('$destroy', unsubscribe);

}
```

I am using JHipster 3.0.0 and angular 1.5.2.
This controller gets entity and displays it.While retrieving 1st entry it prints JSON and displays it but while getting 2nd entry it prints blank { } , but still displays data.My Question is why blank ? .I am sorry if this question sounds naive , i am new to angular. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou oops sorry its 3.0.0 .

Comment: What is `entity` that gets injected in your controller? Is it a service you wrote? it does not seem to be some code generated by JHipster

Comment: The value for 'entity' is usually passed from the resolve property of the state in router configuration file...named something like caption.state.js, you can find example in the *.state.js files.